# What does Xtend in Eclipse actually do?

Tags: java, xtend

I was trying to understand the software [Xtend](https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/101_gettingstarted.html) in Eclipse. I wanted to understand what does it actually do? Is it a software to form a link between Java and other programming platforms?

Could somebody give me a brief idea as to how is Xtend useful?
Thanky ou for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xtend is just a language feature add on for JAVA.

"The added value with Xtend is the very concise way to implement Java classes"
- from: https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.xtend

so it changes some syntax and add some new functionalities which intend to make JAVA programming slightly easier.

It is well integrated so you may use any existing JAVA library. Intro video here:
https://eclipse.org/xtend/ that may help you understand more about it

one example of an Xtend langauge feature is how for each loop are used:

in JAVA:

```
for(String myString : stringCollection){
    //do some work
}
```

In Xtend:

```
stringCollection.forEach[
    //do some work
]
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Is it true that xtend along with Java can be used to generate C files? I am not sure of this particular feature.

Comment: Yes although I am not so familiar with it. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912227/code-generation-with-xtend